# magento: URL querystring for adding product and applying discount coupon to cart

Tags: magento, url, query-string, cart, coupon

I am a newbie, after extensive research and exploration I am able to figure out the following:

To add a product to cart I can use

> /checkout/cart/add?product=***76***&qty=***1***

to apply discount code I can use

> /checkout/cart/couponPost?coupon_code=***WQ9D-XXXX***

The code for it resides in file:

> /public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/controllers/**-**

I would like to add product and apply discount code in one link such as:

> /checkout/cart/couponPost?product=**76**&qty=**1**&coupon_code=**WQ9D-XXXX**

OR

> /checkout/cart/add?product=**76**&qty=**1**&coupon_code=**WQ9D-XXXX**

OR 
Any other means?

Is there a way to get this working? Idea is to embed this link in a newsletter so using one click the user is able to add the product to cart and get discount.

I have tried calling `$this->couponPostAction();` from `function addAction()` and vice-versa but it does not work!

Comment: You could create a custom module that combine the logic from cart/add and cart/couponPost or create static page that make 2 sperate ajax call to add product id and coupon code

Comment: I don't think it is going to work the way you are trying. the controllers called will simply discard the request variables not used. 
you can probably do that with javascript. links to /add?product=X and then just modify your theme's cart/checkout phtml to do document location set to call couponPost

Answer (score 5):

Got it working without modifying the code,

'http://www.example.com/checkout/cart/add?Product=76&qty;=1&return;_url=http://www.example.com/index.php/checkout/cart/couponPost?coupon_code=WQ9D-XXXX&return;_url=http://www.example.com/checkout/cart/'

the return_url has to be encoded.

Please see: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/296763/

Comment: Have been looking for this like 2 years! Nice find!

Comment: your offsite link is no longer valid.

Answer (score 5):

rukpat's answer doesn't work in Magento 1.8. You need to format the URL and query string like so, once you have extended the addAction method of the CartController:

```
http://www.example.com/checkout/cart/add?product=76&qty=1&return_url=http://www.example.com/index.php/checkout/cart/couponPost?coupon_code=WQ9D-XXXX
```

You can also omit the last return_url parameter. There's no need to include the ; (semicolons).

You can also add multiple products to the URL with multiple quantities by simply doing:

```
http://www.example.com/checkout/cart/add?product=76&related_product=28,28,28&return_url=http://www.example.com/index.php/checkout/cart/couponPost?coupon_code=WQ9D-XXXX
```

So simply adding &related_product=28,28,28 with multiple references to the product ID allows you to add multiple quantities of that item. Not very elegant but it works.

Of course, it would be better to extend the addAction method of the CartController.

In order for this solution to work in Magento 1.8 and above, you need to modify the CartController like so:

**NOTE**: Replace 'Namespace' with your own namespace (company name or your name etc).

etc/modules/Namespace_AddProductFromUrl.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_AddProductFromUrl>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Namespace_AddProductFromUrl>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Namespace/AddProductFromUrl/controllers/Checkout/CartController.php

```
<?php
    require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';

    class Namespace_AddProductFromUrl_Checkout_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController {
        # overloaded addAction
        public function addAction()
        {        
            // generate form_key if missing or invalid
            if ( ! ($formKey = $this->getRequest()->getParam('form_key', null)) or $formKey != Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey())
            {
                $this->getRequest()->setParams(array('form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()));
            }        

            // do parent actions
            parent::addAction();
        }
    }
```

app/code/local/Namespace/AddProductFromUrl/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <checkout>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Namespace_AddProductFromUrl before="Mage_Checkout">Namespace_AddProductFromUrl_Checkout</Namespace_AddProductFromUrl>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Comment: Tried this on Magento 1.9 and it does not work properly. I think it needs a different declaration of the module itself. I altered the main CartController.php and it worked but it is not ideal https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56126813/adding-products-to-cart-by-url-gives-404-at-first-access-and-works-on-2nd/56133214#56133214

Answer (score 0):

I can verify that Gaz's code with above with Namespace_AddProductFromUrl does work on 1.8

In addition, if by chance your product is a bundled one, you have to use this format url:

[http://domain.com/en/checkout/cart/add?product=24&qty=1&bundle_option[2]=4&bundle_option[3]=8](http://domain.com/en/checkout/cart/add?product=24&qty=1&bundle_option%5b2%5d=4&bundle_option%5b3%5d=8)

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer.